# Servlet Filter pattern to filter URLS outsite some path

Tags: java, servlets, filter

In this kind of application tree:

```
webapp
|---WEB-INF
|---user
    |---home.xhtml
|---login.xhtml
|---register.xhtml
```

I know that if I want to allow only logged in users to acess the **/user/** pages I just need to create a Servlet Filter with this patterns:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "UserFilter", urlPatterns = {"/user/*"})
public class UserFilter implements Filter { ... }
```

but what if I want to prevent a logged In user to access the **login.xhtml** and **register.xhtml** pages?
I was wondering if there is a way of doing this using just one pattern, and not using

```
urlPatterns = {
            "/login.xhtml",
            "/register.xhtml"
        }
```

Thank you for any help